# How To Make Text In SVG Clickable But Not Underlined

Tags: javascript, svg, hyperlink, underline

I am using JavaScript to put a text element inside an SVG element.
My motivation is to dynamically draw a logo which includes text. 
I want to make the whole SVG element clickable to link to another page.
This all works, except that I don't want the text inside the box to be underlined like other links are.

The code below is a stripped-down version which demonstrates what I am trying to do. As you can see, I have commented out two different setAttribute() calls; I tried both of them but neither suppressed the underline.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<title>Test SVG Text As Link</title>
<style>
.no-underline {
  text-decoration:none;
}
</style>
<script>
// Defined symbolic constants
var SVG_NS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";

/* Draws the box with text in it.
* Parameter:
*   id = String containing the ID of the SVG element to draw into.
*/
function drawBox(id) {
  var box = document.getElementById(id); // Find the SVG element
  // How big should the text be?
  var fontSize = '20px';
  // Now make the text boxes
  var line1 = makeText(20, 180, 50, 180, 
    'green', 1, 'green', fontSize, 'Arial', 'Some text');
  //line1.setAttribute("style", "text-decoration:none");
  //line1.setAttribute("class", ".no-underline");
  box.appendChild(line1);
}

/*
*  Constructs a textbox that can be added to the SVG
*  element at (x, y)
*
*  Parameters:
*    x, y, height, width in pixels
*    strokeColor, fillColor
*    strokeWidth in pixels
*    fontSize in points, presumably
*    text
*
*  Returns: The text element
*/
function makeText(x, y, height, width, strokeColor, strokeWidth,
     fillColor, fontSize, fontFamily, text) {
  var newBox = document.createElementNS(SVG_NS,"text");
  newBox.setAttributeNS(null,"x", x);
  newBox.setAttributeNS(null,"y", y);
  newBox.setAttributeNS(null,"height", height);
  newBox.setAttributeNS(null,"width", width);
  newBox.setAttributeNS(null,"stroke", strokeColor);
  newBox.setAttributeNS(null,"stroke-width", strokeWidth);
  newBox.setAttributeNS(null,"fill", fillColor);
  newBox.setAttributeNS(null,"font-size",fontSize);
  newBox.setAttributeNS(null,"font-family", fontFamily);
  newBox.textContent = text;
  return newBox;
}
</script>
</head>
<a href="foo.html">
<body onload="drawBox('svgBox');" >
<svg width="200" height="200" id="svgBox">
</svg>
<br/>
Could also click here.
</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try to append text-decoration="none" to text element.

Comment: @defghi1977 That has no effect.

Comment: Hmm.. that's interesting. It happens in Chrome and FF, but not IE.  That seems like a bug to me.  There doesn't seem to be any way to turn off the underline. http://jsfiddle.net/fhcw9w50/1/

Answer (score 2):

Seems like a bug in FF and Chrome.

A workaround is to not wrap your SVG in a `<a>` element.  Instead, put the `<a>` inside the SVG, like so:

```
<svg width="200" height="200" id="svgBox"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <a xlink:href="foo.html">
    <text id="foo" x="20" y="180">Some text</text>
  </a>
</svg>
<br/>
<a href="foo.html">
Could also click here.
</a>
```

You can then disable the underline with CSS.

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/fhcw9w50/6/)

Comment: I have reported this issue to Chrome (https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=406966) and FF (https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1057921).

Comment: Thanks, BigBadaboom, for both the answer and the bug report. Some issues: #1: Using Firefox 31.0 on Ubuntu 14.04, your Demo does not work; neither the SVG as a whole nor the text inside it actually acts as a link. #2: I want to make the entire SVG clickable, not just the text. #3: What I ultimately want to accomplish is a JavaScript function which draws the logo (including graphics and text) into an empty SVG element at any size (I have that working). but then sometimes I might want it clickable and sometimes not.

Comment: Re #1 There was a typo, I had fixed the answer, but not the demo. Try again now.  Re #2 To make the background clickable, use a transparent `<rect>`, see: http://jsfiddle.net/fhcw9w50/7/

Comment: Unless FF and Chrome do a U-turn on their interpretation of the CSS spec (unlikely :), Robert's answer is the one you should probably accept.  You could use my solution, but it is easier to simply use separate `<a>` elements for your SVG and the outside text. Then turn underline off for the SVG one.

Comment: Actually I was wrong, the SVG specification has wording to override CSS. Firefox and Chrome may need to change. http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/text.html#TextDecorationProperties

Answer (score 2):

OK, I seem to have it working now. What I wound up doing was wrapping the entire SVG in an anchor ("a") tag, and manually putting the 'style="text-decoration:none;" ' attribute in the anchor tag, rather than on the inner text (by "manually" I mean that I typed it into the HTML rather than generating it with JavaScript). Like this:

```
<a href="foo.html" style="text-decoration:none">
<svg ...> Everything inside here will get added by JavaScript
</svg>
</a>
```

Thanks to everyone for their suggestions.